# What happens to cards cast from exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are a few cards that allow you to exile cards and then cast them later ([Narset, Enlightened Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Narset%2C%20Enlightened%20Master) for example). After a spell cast this way resolves, does it go back into exile, or does it resolve normally including being placed in its owner's graveyard? (assuming nothing else effects where it would go after being cast)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens to a spell after it's been cast is not affected by where it was cast from. It's the usual rule about cards being by default "reset" whenever they move from a zone to another.

Unless the spell itself (e.g. [Pull from the Deep](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPull%20from%20the%20Deep%5d), [White Sun's Zenith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433010)...) or another card (such as [Rest in Peace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRest%20in%20Peace%5d)) says it doesn't go to the graveyard, that is where it will end up.

Answer (score -8):

If a card is exiled and played, then when it dies it will go back to exile,this is because when its exiled it is considered to be "out of the game" but it is still usable if you cast it, this is just the same as [Spawnsire of Ulamog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpawnsire%20of%20Ulamog%5d)'s ability or the affect from [Coax from the Blind Eternities](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCoax%20from%20the%20Blind%20Eternities%5d).

Comment: This is incorrect. A card doesn't care that it came from graveyard, or hand or exile unless it's ability says it does. When a spell is cast from exile, that spell goes to graveyard, unless it otherwise says to exile it. If you cast say [Skittering Invasion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193614) from your sideboard for Spawnsire, it goes to graveyard. Creatures go to graveyard when they die unless they are told to exile, like with unearth.

Comment: Praetors grasp exiles a card facedown and you may look at and play that card as long as it is exiled what would be the point of this card if after playing it it is just put in the grave. Then it would say play that card then return it to its owners graveyard

Comment: The card remains in exile, until you cast it. Once you cast it it resolves as normal, including going back to the owner's grave. the meaning of "as long as it remains in exile" means you don't have to cast it immediately, you may wait and cast it, but once you do it is handled as normal.

Comment: But I can drop leyline of the void or planar void and keep it exiled so I can play it right?

Comment: No. once you cast it it leaves exile, going on the stack, the fact that it goes back to exile after you cast it does not change the fact that it has left exile.

Comment: It is not useless, one it removes it from the opponents deck, so they can no longer cast that copy themselves, and second it lets you cast it. Say it's Emrakul, instead of them getting to cast their bomb, you cast it, though you do still need to be able to pay the cost.

Comment: Are their any loophole cause I always used it to exile a counter spell of some kind so I can be captain dickhead

Comment: Nope, if it has said you may cast a copy, that would be what work. What you are looking for is [Isochron Scepter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212626) with [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=429869) or even better [Mana Drain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438631). This combo lets you cast a counter spell once per round at least.

Comment: Another option is [Deadeye Navigator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425861) and [Mystic Snake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405316), the navigator flickers the snake and every time the snake enters it counters something.
[Glen Elendra Archmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370522) and [Melira](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194274) works for non creature, since Melira prevents the persist from turning off.

Comment: Oh, ok thks bruh you were a big help

Comment: Also exile is not considered to be outside the game, this is why Coax refers to both outside the game and in exile separately. The exile zone is a zone of the game, what is considered by the game to be "outside the game" is almost always the sideboard, in casual outside the game can be anything the players agree on.[IE everything you own]

Comment: @Andrew I think it is the confusion from old cards mentioning "removing from the game" = Exile and the concept of "outside of the game", meaning sideboard or in the case of spawn of Ulamog, your trade binder if you wanted to (in casual play)